# Unable to extend baking / simulation end frame for soft body animation

Tags: physics, baking, soft-body

I am building a soft body animation, and want to Simulate up to eg frame 140, check simulation and then simulate frames 141 - 200, and so on...

However to change the simulation start and end frames, it obliges to delete all the Bake and restart simulation from scratch. Why ?

[image]

That's not really efficient to resimulate everything each time, especially for animations that are 3000 frames+, and with simulation running 2fps.

Is there an efficient way to run simulations, freeze them, then continue them ?